# Populate a textbox with values from checked boxes in InfoPath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

The problem I'm dealing with involves three separate lists originating from the same site. There is the list the form is attached to(Form List), a list of assets (Asset List), and a list with information from that asset list in text form(Info List). I am attempting to store data from the Info List brought in by a data connection. The user will first select a number of assets (populated by the Asset List) from a checkbox list. The user will then press a button that should populate several text boxes with the information from the Asset List. This information is filtered using the device name, which is the value of the checkboxes:

```
xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Eval(xdXDocument:GetDOM("Asset List")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Title[contains(../d:Serial, string(xdXDocument:get-DOM()/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/my:SharePointListItem_RW/my:Device_x0020_Name/Value))], 'concat(., " | ")'), "..")
```

However, when I run this, the box is populated by ALL of the data in the Asset List instead of just the ones that have been checked. Am I doing something wrong here?